# Increasing vertices in psychopy to create progress bar

Tags: python, psychopy

I am trying to create a progress bar for an fMRI task, so that when a participant answers correctly, the progress bar moves up exponentially based on the trial amount/questions left. 
I have figured out how to make the bar move up only to a specified value (as shown below) but I cannot seem to get it to move up every correct question by lets say 10%..

I place the progress bar function in the 'each frame' code component of the routine.

```
progverts = [ [0,-0.8], [0,-0.7], [0.2,-0.7] ,[0.2,-0.8] ]

counter = 0

progTest = visual.ShapeStim(win, units='', lineWidth=1.5, lineColor='red', lineColorSpace='rgb', 
   fillColor='yellow', fillColorSpace='rgb', vertices=progverts, 
   closeShape=True, pos=(0, 0), size=1, ori=0.0, opacity=1.0,
   contrast=1.0, depth=0, interpolate=True, name=None, autoLog=None, autoDraw = False)

def progressbar ():
   global counter 
   global progverts 

   progTest.setAutoDraw(True)
   win.flip()
   core.wait(.5)

   if trials.thisN == 0: 
       if ParticipantKeys.corr  == 1:
           progTest.vertices = [ [0,-0.8], [0,-0.65], [0.2,-0.65] ,[0.2,-0.8] ]
```

Essentially, I am trying to figure out a way to make progverts[1] and progverts[2] increase their y-axis every correct answer..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It might be helpful if you describe a little more what you've tried and what the specific results were.  Is there an error?  If so, please edit your post to include it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what else to add, this is the closest I can get to my desired result without error. I just don't know how to access the vertices within the function to redraw y-axes..

Comment: You're overthinking it. Once the stimulus is created, you just need to scale it by updating its size parameter. And the stimulus doesn't even need to be created in code. Just insert a four-sided polygon component in Builder, with a size of, say `[0.1, 0.1]`. The in the 'each frame' tab, increment `counter` as required and do something like  `progTest.size = [0.1, 0.1*counter]`. Also, never do `win.flip()` and `core.wait()` in Builder code. This will break Builder's drawing cycle (i.e. such code is no longer fitting within the "each frame" domain).

Comment: Thanks Michael, I actually already had a progress bar like this by adjusting the size like you said, (although you beyond simplified my code for that one). However, I only want the y axis to move up, in the comment you made, the y axis moves up and down simultaneously..

Comment: @shai73 I'm not sure what you mean by "the y axis moves up and down simultaneously"? The scaling factor above (`[0.1, 0.1*counter]`) should hold the *x* size constant at 0.1, and scale the *y* size independently. Can you explain more precisely the issue?

Comment: When I plug in your comment, the y axis expands the polygon shape by adding 0.1 in the positive and negative direction. In other words the vertices go from [ [0,-0.8], [0,-0.7], [0.2,-0.7] ,[0.2,-0.8] ] to [ [0,-0.9], [0,-0.6], [0.2,-0.6] ,[0.2,-0.9] ]. However, I just figured out that if I put:    'if counter < 10:
    counter += 1

    a = (-0.7 + (.2*counter))
    b = (-0.7 + (.2*counter))
    progTest5.vertices = [ [0,-0.8], [0,a], [0.2,b] ,[0.2,-0.8] ]
    core.wait(1)    The y axis will only expand vertically in the positive direction

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill also, if you suggest never to use core.wait, how can I make the counter add 1 count per second, as opposed to per frame?

Comment: This is now turning into a dialog... At no point in the question did you mention making the counter increase as a function of time: it was posed as a function of questions correct. As @JeffL. suggest, you need to re-work your question... On the vertices issue, at least one needs to be anchored at [0,0] for scaling to work properly. Use the position attribute of the stimulus to place it onscreen where needed, not the vertices themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. Read the comments in the code below to learn why I've changed a few things here and there. I've answered your question as if this was a pure code problem first. However, it seems that you may be working through a Builder code component so there's a Builder version below.

## Coder version

```py
# Some parameters.
RISE_SPEED = 0.02  # how much to increase height in each frame. (here 2% increase every frame)
RISE_END = 1.0  # end animation at this unit height

# Set up the window and bar. 
from psychopy import visual
win = visual.Window()
progTest = visual.Rect(win, width=0.2, height=0.1, pos=(0, -0.75), 
                       lineColor='red', fillColor='yellow')  # no need to set all the default parameters. Just change the ones you need

# While the height is less than RISE_END.
while progTest.height < RISE_END:
    # Increase the height (y-length in both directions) and then move up on Y so that the base stays put.
    progTest.height *= 1 + RISE_SPEED
    progTest.pos[1] += progTest.height*RISE_SPEED/2  # the y-position only

    # Show it. 
    progTest.draw()
    win.flip()
```

Notice that since you're just using a rectangle bar, `visual.Rect` is handy since it has a `height` parameter. Behind the scenes, `visual.Rect` is just a `visual.ShapeStim`, but the `Rect` way is easier to create and manipulate rectangles which is a frequent enough use case to warrant it's existence.

## Builder version

Simply have this in the "run each frame" section of a code component and make sure to have`progTest` in the same routine, created using Builder.

```py
RISE_SPEED = 0.02  # how much to increase height in each frame. (here 2% increase every frame)
RISE_END = 1.0  # end animation at this unit height
progTest.height *= 1 + RISE_SPEED
progTest.pos[1] += progTest.height*RISE_SPEED/2  # the y-position only
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you can probably tell Im new to coding in general but this really helped.

Comment: If this worked well for you, you can upvote and/or accept the answer, to indicate to others that it solved the problem. StackOverflow will then be a repository of good questions and good answers.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but given my <15 reputation, it will not be displayed publicly.